# Java Graphics, нарисовать круг

Tags: java, swing, graphics

Необходимо на фрейме нарисовать круг, фрейм создал.
Использую метод `paint()`. Не могу понять почему не рисует?
Еще может кто нормальных курсов подкинет или книжек?
Чтобы уже что-то более конкретное (к примеру, типов переменных) и какие бывают циклы?

Код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new MainWindow();
        window.paint();
    }
}

public class MainWindow extends JFrame{
    MainWindow() {
        super("Main window");
        setSize(400,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawOval(20,40,200,150);
    }
}
```

Comment: Переписал, теперь круг рисуется.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame{
    MainWindow() {
        super("Main window for game");
        setSize(400,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawOval(150,100,75,75);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Вы можете создать отдельный класс нужной отрисовки, на примере эллипса:**
[image: Создание отдельного класса]

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Draw extends JPanel {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int zoom = 1;
    Draw() {
        setSize(400,300);
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    Draw(Ellipse ellipse, int zoom) {
        setSize(1000,1000);
        setVisible(true);

        this.zoom = zoom < 1 ? 1 : zoom;
        this.x = ellipse.getCenterPoint().x;
        this.y = ellipse.getCenterPoint().y;
        this.width = ellipse.getHalf_axis_B();
        this.height = ellipse.getHalf_axis_A();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        super.setVisible(true);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawOval(x, y, width * zoom, height * zoom);
    }
}
```

**В данном коде используется конструктор в который передается кастомный класс Draw(Ellipse)**
**Переписываем метод paintComponent:**

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    super.setVisible(true);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawOval(x, y, width * zoom, height * zoom);
}
```

[**Что такое - @Override**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-in-java/)

**В MAIN файле создаем область видимости JFrame в который добавляем экземпляр класса и передаем в конструктор параметры Draw(ellipse, 10):**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(2, 3);

        System.out.printf(ellipse.print());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Ellipse");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new Draw(ellipse, 100));

    }
}
```